# Weird error using Android License server

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

So following the instruction from the official android developers website I've set up everything to create a license check, but I am having the weirdest of the errors...

I've created 3 activities for the 3 posible responses from the license server:

-EverythingOkActivity

-NotLicensedActivity

-ErrorActivity

Each one should be launched depending on the server's response, But...

When I connect my phone to debug my app, if the condition to launch the **ErrorActivity** is meet, then it launches the **NotLicensedActivity** intent and viceversa, if the condition to launch the **NotLicensedActivity** intent is meet, then it launches the **ErrorActivity** intent.

Plus I am never able to launch the **EverythingOkActivity**, I've already setup my test gmail account on the developer console and selected **LICENSED** at the license test response on my account, I've also uploaded the APK.

The debug console shows this response from the server:

```
I/LicenseChecker: Received response.
I/LicenseChecker: Clearing timeout.
```

But no errors at least I have no internet, in that case is shows:

```
I/LicenseChecker: Received response.
I/LicenseChecker: Clearing timeout.
W/LicenseValidator: Error contacting licensing server.
```

And then launches the intent to **NotLicensedActivity** instead of **ErrorActivity**

I have no idea what could be wrong, Excuse me if I am Android noob.

Here is the code of my Main Activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.AESObfuscator;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseCheckerCallback;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.ServerManagedPolicy;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "MIIBIjANBgkq[...]";
    private static final byte[] SALT = new byte[] {
            -44, 55, 30, -128, -103, -57, 74, -64, 51, 88, -95, -45, 77, -117, -36, -113, -11, 32, -64,
            89
    };
    private LicenseCheckerCallback mLicenseCheckerCallback;
    private LicenseChecker mChecker;
    private boolean keepGoing = true;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();
        mChecker = new LicenseChecker(this, new ServerManagedPolicy(this,
                new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)),
                BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);
        doCheck();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!keepGoing) {
            finish();
        }
    }
    private void doCheck() {
        mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
    }
    private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {
        public void allow(int policyReason) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EverythingOkActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        public void dontAllow(int policyReason) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                return;
            }
            keepGoing = false;
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotLicensedActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        public void applicationError(int errorCode) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                return;
            }
            keepGoing = false;
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ErrorActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mChecker.onDestroy();  //Don't forget this line. Without it, your app might crash.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved!!! The problem is the app needs to be published in the Play Store at least as an Alpha and then you need to add a list a Alpha-tester users (in this case myself) to the app. Is not enough to to upload the APK, you need to actually publish the app to get the license to work. I will let that code here as a example, since it works like a charm. Cheers (^_^)